# Scala: benchmark methods' speed by time: Total runtime for methods

Tags: scala

I have two ways of finding factorial using Scala. I want to find out how much slower non-tail recursive way is compared to tail-recursive way.

```scala
// factorial non-tail recursive
def fact1(n: Int): Int =
  if (n==0) 1
  else n*fact(n-1)       

// factorial tail recursive
def fact(n: Int): Int = {
  def loop(acc: Int, n:Int): Int =
    if (n==0) acc
    else loop(acc*n, n-1)
  loop(1, n)
}

// a1 = Time.now
fact1(100)
// a2 = Time.now
// a2-a1

// b1 = Time.now
fact(100)
// b2 = Time.now
// b2-b1
```

I just wrote up Ruby code for Time.now. Basically, how would you write `Time.now` like code in Scala?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `java.lang.System` class which provides methods for computing the current time:

- `currentTimeMillis` for the current time in milliseconds
- `nanoTime` for the current time in nanoseconds (which is recommended now).

However, writing good micro-benchmarks is very difficult and it is recommended to rely on a framework for that. Caliper is really good and there is a [nice template for projects in scala](https://github.com/sirthias/scala-benchmarking-template).

Answer (score 0):

You may use the Scala wrapper method `scala.compat.Platform.currentTime` which forwards the call to `System.currentTimeMillis`.

Comment: what is the thinking behind using the wrapper rather than the java method?

Comment: If you use a wrapper, and later decide to port your code to ScalaJS, or some other target, it will still work.